# How to create drag drop navigation menu manager like wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery, css, drag-and-drop

I have built a simple CMS, but stuck at how to manage navigation menu from admin area, I want it to be as navigation menus in Wordpress which can drag and drop and give some indent for child menu.

So far I just create `nav_menu` table which contain `id, object_id, parent_id, order` fields.

I think with above table I can create as many menu as I want.

So can you please suggest me some tutorials related with my question, or maybe you can give me idea like what jquery component needed or something regarding my question.

Hope there's is updated tutorial about this.

Thanks.